# Obuiselector Reference in openbravo should take record on last 4 digit input

Tags: reference, openbravo

i have created an reference selector that populate an machine no. but on basis of starting digit

I need the machine number to be populate on the basis of last 4 digit

Example:
suppose i have a machine no as 10100000060

"if i type 1010 starting 4 digit of machine no it populate the record in drop down".

now if i type 0060 last 4 digit it wont populate the record .

so i need to populate the record in drop down on basis of last 4 digit.